# Winform ListViewItem Checked Status Toggle

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with race conditions with winforms.

```
  listViewCollections.ItemChecked += foo //Somewhere

  void foo(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.Checked == false) return;
        bool flag = bar( e.Item.Index);
        if (flag) {
            MessageBox.Show( ... )
            e.Item.Checked = false;
       }
    }
```

Sometimes the message box shows twice. What's the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you programmatically setting the items as checked? The only way I can reproduce your problem is by setting more than one item as checked programmatically.

Comment: Yes, actually right after the first if clause there's a loop that clears (sets to false) some other checkboxes in the same ListView. I didn't think it would be relevant. I would expect some events to get fired and then be caught by the first if conditional.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just put a simple lock around it?  Also I would suggest switching the way the Checked logic works to simplify the function a little (remove the mid-function return)

```
private static object fooLock = new object();
void foo(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (fooLock)
    {
        if (e.Item.Checked) 
        {
            if (bar(e.Item.Index)) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show( ... )
                e.Item.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Numerous ways to improve the performance, but that should at least stop the race conditions?